# Change standard date format fetched from database Y-M-D into D-M-Y

Tags: php, database

I am able to fetch data from a database using php. I have a field which is "DATE" but when i get the date displayed is in the format YEAR/MONTH/DAY. Is this because the standard format of the value "DATE" is that or there is any other option or way I can use in order to show the date in the format DAY/MONTH/YEAR ?? thank you

I am usinf MYSQL and php

```
here is the code:
$query = "SELECT * FROM trip";
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo "<table >"; 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   
if ($row['Day'] == date("Y-m-d"))
{
echo '<tr class="today">';
}
else {echo "<tr>";
}
echo "<td>" . $row['Day'] . "</td>

}
echo "</table>"; 
mysql_close(); ?>
```

----- new code ----

```
 include('includes/connection.php');

    // $connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); 

$sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT *
    FROM `trip`

SQL;

if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "<table >"; 
                    {   
                    if ($row['Day'] == date("Y-m-d"))
                    {
                    echo '<tr class="today">';
                    }
                    else {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    }
                    echo "<td>" . date('d/m/Y', strtotime($row['Day'])) . "</td>

                    <td>" . $row['Country'] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row['Place'] . "</td>

                    </tr>";  //$row['index'] the index here is a field name
                    }
                    echo "</table>"; //Close the table in HTML

}
```

Comment: How you change this will differ between various databases so you need to tell us what specific database you are using? If it's MySQL you can use the `date_format()` function to control how the date is displayed. See this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: if this is a `php` question, please add a `php` tag

Comment: `mysql_` functions are deprecated, use `mysqli_` instead.

Comment: thank you. I will have a look about how to use the msqli_ insetad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format it with php.

For example:
You can do something like
date('d/m/Y', strtotime($database_date));
http://php.net/manual/de/function.date.php

base on your code - this will do the work:

```
date('d/m/Y', strtotime($row['Day']))
```

If you need to format the date based of a users locale, you can use strftime. http://php.net/manual/de/function.strftime.php

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM trip";
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo "<table >"; 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   
    if ($row['Day'] == date("Y-m-d"))
    {
         echo '<tr class="today">';
    }
    else {
         echo "<tr>";
    }
    echo "<td>" . date('d/m/Y', strtotime($row['Day'])) . "</td>";
}

echo "</table>"; 
mysql_close(); ?>
```